# Disable "Browse" button if the radio button isn't selected

Tags: javascript

```
<form action="" method="post" name="site_avatar" id="avatar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="radio" name="avatar" value="gravatar" />
<input type="radio" name="avatar" value="local" />
<input size="25" name="file" type="file" />
<input name="site_avatar" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is my form with two radio buttons and one image upload field. I want to keep the "Browse" button disabled if the second radion button isn't selected (with the value "local").

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can't you just disable the file-input? That should disable the Browse button, too...

Comment: I use jquery on my so it doesn't metter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/ohusa3/2/)]

**Javascript**

```
var form = document.getElementById("avatar");
var second = form.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
var file = document.getElementById("file");

form.onchange = function() {
  if (second.checked) {
    file.disabled = false;
  } else {
    file.disabled = "disabled";
  }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input size="25" name="file" id="file" type="file" />
```

I would suggest you revisiting the names & ids in the form btw, because they are kinda messed up. :)

Comment: Works fine but there is a little problem. If the second radio button is selected by default, i.e. checked="checked" tag is added, the button is still disabled... So user has to check the first button and that check the second again to activate the "Browse" button...

Comment: 1.) be the first one the default 2.) if the second one is the default, make the browse enabled by default (both works...)